# Ingesting inline into Kusto

Tags: bigdata, azure-data-explorer, kql

Can we ingest records inline into Kusto using an ingestion mapping reference? Suppose I have some records for testing and wanted to ingest it using an ingestion mapping reference from the Kusto console. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If this is for testing the mapping, you can use the "Ingest New Data" experience in the [Web explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/web-query-data) tool, or the "Import data from local files" button in the [Kusto Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/tools/kusto-explorer) tool.

If you are doing inline ingestion, the "[.append](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query)" command will be easier. and to your question, yes you can do it by specifying the mapping using the [ingestion property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingestion-properties): "ingestionMapping"